# Python Selenium click button with no name, no id, no text, many classes, and an aria-label

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

Here is the button:

```
<button _ngcontent-qte-c250="" mat-raised-button="" color="primary" aria-label="Close Welcome Banner" class="mat-focus-indicator close-dialog mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><mat-icon _ngcontent-qte-c250="" role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font"> visibility_off </mat-icon><span _ngcontent-qte-c250="" fxshow="" fxhide.lt-sm="" translate="">Dismiss</span></span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button>
```

How do I even go about clicking this?
Tried doing what [this](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/17998130.html) link says, but Xpath does not seem to like working with many classes

Tried the following, nothing seems to work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Close Welcome Banner']/div[@class='mat-focus-indicator close-dialog mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary ng-start-inserted']");
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Close Welcome Banner']").click()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'middle') and contains(text(), 'Next')]"))
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a `button` tag, not a `div`

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Close Welcome Banner']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find xpath for button tag by text.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Dismiss')]")
```